# Can Apache virtual hosts be set up to redirect to a Docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, apache2, port, virtualhost

I have a Docker container running Apache that is currently listening to the port 80.

I am trying to run another website on the same server, using Apache natively this time, also listening to the port 80.

The problem is that I cannot have both applications listening to the same port (Docker and Apache).

Can I set up the server’s native Apache installation to redirect internally certain requests based on the domain name to my Docker container? For instance, Apache would listen to the port 80 and requests to `mycontainer.com` would be internally transferred to the port `9999` to which Docker would listen.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that. The first time I wanted to test, this is the way I did and worked with no issue.

We have an Apache container running to port 80, and let us call another domain like `mycontainer.com` that we want to be accessible on port 80 too but we cannot.

No matter how do you run these containers, I mean by `docker run` or `docker-compose`, but the point is they should be in the same **network**.

Create a network called `my_network`:

```
docker network create my_network
```

I call the first Apache as **main** and the latter as **the_name** one.

So now let us run both in the same network:

```
docker run --name main --network my_network httpd
docker run --name the_name --network my_network another_image
```

Now you can exec into the `the_name` container and create a `domain.conf` file in Apache conf path with below contents:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName mycontainer.com

        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass "/" "http://the_name:9999/"
        ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://the_name:9999/"
        ProxyRequests Off

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

I Guess it is possible with Apache named virtual host and Proxy Pass.
You can try something like below. Just make sure you enabled apache `mod_proxy`.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName app-running-in-docker-container.com

    ErrorLog "var/log/container_error_log"
    CustomLog "var/log/container_access_log" common

    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:999
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:999
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName app-running-natively.com
    DocumentRoot /path/to/project/doc/root
    ErrorLog "var/log/nativelyapp_error_log"
    CustomLog "var/log/nativelyapp_access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```